# How to compute GitLab deploy key fingerprint from ssh key-pair

Tags: ssh-keys, fingerprint, gitlab

When viewing Deploy Keys in a GitLab repository's setting, the keys have a "name" and also some kind of fingerprint. The fingerprint looks like this:

```
2b:be:a7:7f:44:64:89:8d:e3:f7:ea:3c:12:c9:e5:e7
```

I am trying to find out which of my ssh key-pairs this one corresponds to. How do I compute this string from an existing ssh key-pair?

Answer (score 12):

SSH key fingerprints are simply hashes of entire public-key block (the large `AAAA...=` blob in your id_rsa.pub). First Base64-decode that field, then compute its MD5 or SHA256 hash, finally print it in hex (for MD5) or Base64 (for SHA256).

You can compute the fingerprints manually...

```
cat id_rsa.pub | awk '{print $2}' | base64 -d | md5sum

cat id_rsa.pub | awk '{print $2}' | base64 -d | openssl dgst -md5 -c

awk '{print $2}' id_rsa.pub | base64 -d | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | base64
```

...or ask OpenSSH to do it (more convenient because it'll accept private key files too):

```
ssh-keygen -l -f <keyfile>
```

Newer OpenSSH versions instead use a SHA256 hash and encode the fingerprint to Base64, not hex. To force a new OpenSSH *ssh-keygen* to show you the MD5 fingerprint, just add `-E md5`:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f <keyfile> -E md5
```